# Not Scrolling in scroll view

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview

The parent is relative layout and then in it is an image view and a scroll view and in the scroll view is another relative layout.
When tested in phone it is not scrolling down.
Please help with the fix.
There are edit text components and a button inside the relative layout inside the scroll view.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/MistyRose">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/reglogo"
android:layout_width="200sp"
android:layout_height="150sp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/logo" />

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/reglogo"
android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-551dp"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

Comment: ScrollView cannot scroll while being empty. If it has other views include them also.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the LinearLayout to scroll a view as well wrap_content

```
  <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/MistyRose">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/reglogo"
android:layout_width="200sp"
android:layout_height="150sp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/logo" />

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/reglogo"
android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-551dp"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the child RelativeLayout's height as `match parent`. This means that the RelativeLayout has the same height as the ScrollView. Thus there's nothing to scroll through because they're the same height!

Comment: If I put wrap content I am  not able to place new elements to bottom